# Which method is best to pass data from view to controller codeigniter?

Tags: html, ajax, forms

I am using codeigniter 3 and I am new for codeigniter. I want to ask that which method is more suitable to pass data from view to controller, using jquery or `<form action="controller/method">`

I am trying to pass data using jquery but it does not giving any response and no error will be shown. Jquery code is given:

```
function registration()
    {            
        var txtemail = document.getElementById("email").value;
        $.post("<?php echo site_url('Home/registration'); ?>", {checkEmail: txtemail, action: "registerUser"},
        function(data) {                
            var result = data + "";
            if (result.lastIndexOf("Success") > -1) {

            } else {
                var txtUser = document.getElementById("username").value;
                var txtContact = document.getElementById("contact").value;
                var txtEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;
                var txtpincode = document.getElementById("pincode").value;
                var txtCity = document.getElementById('city').value;
                var txtState = document.getElementById('state').value;
                var txtCountry = document.getElementById("country").value;
                var txtPackage = document.getElementById("package").value;

                var registerMstData = new Array();
                registerMstData[0] = txtUser;
                registerMstData[1] = txtContact;
                registerMstData[2] = txtEmail;
                registerMstData[3] = txtpincode;
                registerMstData[4] = txtCity;
                registerMstData[5] = txtState;
                registerMstData[6] = txtCountry;
                registerMstData[7] = txtPackage;

                $.post("<?php echo site_url('Home/registration') ?>", {pageData: registerMstData, action: "save"},
                function(data) {                
                    var result = data + "";
                    window.alert(result);
                })
                .fail(function(req, status, err) {
                    console.error('Error : ' + err + " status : " + status + " request " + req.toString());
                    alert('Error : ' + err + " status : " + status + " request " + req.toString());
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

What I am doing wrong I don't understand? Please help.

Comment: this has nothing to do with codeigniter

Comment: Wow, not even finished the sentence... new level of question quality.

Comment: It shows response [Object object]. What is Object?

Comment: `var result = data + "";` this basically does `toString()` on object that you get. String representation of object is `[Object object]`. Don't do alert there, but set a break point and look what you've got in the object.

Answer (score 0):

I personally think that AJAX should be used for displays updates and form submissions should be done via a page reload.

- a form submission is synchronous and it reloads the page.
- an ajax call is asynchronous and it does not reload the page.

It all depends on how you want it to be

**Update**

For ajax, you can use

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'your url',
   data: {
       format: 'json'
   },
   error: function(err) {
      // handle error here
   },
   data: yourData
   success: function(data) {
      // handle success here
   },
   type: 'POST'
});
```

Comment: how should I check actual errors? Is there any parameters for error : function() { }

Comment: @ApurvaMatey, updated my answer. `error` function has a parameter for error